# Changing color characters with pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm writing my own version of matrix raining code. Below I have a loop.

```
chars = []

for char in characters:
    item = font.render(char, True, (random.randrange(
        0, 100), 255, random.randrange(0, 100)))
    chars.append(item)
```

I'm trying to change the color by clicking left, right, down etc. When i press the keys they give me input on the terminal, but I have no idea how to bind those two.

```
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                quit()
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                colour = red
                print('red')
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                colour = blue
                print('blue')
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                colour = cyan
                print('cyan')
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                colour = magenta
                print('magenta')
```

I simplified the for loop to this

```
chars = []

for char in characters:
    item = font.render(char, True, (pygame.color))
    chars.append(item)

    if event.key == pygame.K_g:
        color = (0, 255, 0)
```

But now i'm getting error

```
TypeError: invalid color argument
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        run = False
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            quit()
        elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            colour = red
            print('red')
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            colour = blue
            print('blue')
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            colour = cyan
            print('cyan')
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            colour = magneta
            print('magenta')

        for char in characters:
            item = font.render(char, True, colour)
            chars.append(item)
```

Comment: No it does not work, because there are many `item`s in a list.

Comment: Please do not post code-only answers, an explanation would be helpful for author and other readers to understand your intent.

Comment: I made it work.